# Best practices for URL with space and special characters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently modifying a small web application. This web application allow users to enter / specify a category themselves. I noticed that in the database, there's plenty of category that contain spaces and special characters, like for example Cakes & cupcakes.

On the front-end, the database shows all the user defined categories in the form of URL links and user can click on them to further see what's in the category.

The front-end category links are encoded using the rawurlencode function and it looks something like this.

```
./show.php?category=<?php echo rawurlencode($e['category']); ?>
```

And on the back-end, a function will `GET` the URL and then decode it before it's being sent to the database for querying.

```
$category = rawurldecode(htmlspecialchars_decode($category));
```

It works fine but it seems somewhat 'last-minute' and 'unsophisticated'.

As such I'm wondering, what is the best practice in PHP for URL special characters and spaces?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the "slug" method.  You could "slugify" the strings and use the slug in the url.

http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php

You'll need to add a column to the database for the slug, but then you can easily represent user input fields in the url and make them readable.  "function-to-slugify-strings-in-php" is a slug that probably originally looked something like "Function to slugify strings in PHP".

Comment: Hi xyld, thanks for your input. Correct me if I'm wrong, we just add a new column to the database for the slug string and use it as the URL value while using the values from the existing category column as the link text. Sounds like a good solution and search-engine friendly too. However, I still think it would be best used with URL rewrite as show.php?category=Cakes-and-cupcakes still does not look somewhat sophisticated. But thanks for the brilliant suggestion and much appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you find a better solution?