# PHP encoding url empty spaces

Tags: php, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices for URL with space and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795580/best-practices-for-url-with-space-and-special-characters)

I'm trying to make "pretty" url, and i was wondering how do people deal with empty spaces, for example if I'm creating a new forum thread with a title:

`awesome thread title`

I would like to replace empty space with `-` symbol, so I should get something like:

`http://website.com/forum/thread/awesome-thread-title`

Now it seems to be working but what should i do if user wrote

`some-title`

This would break my code when fetching record from the database, because i would replace `-` symbol to empty space while row name in the database would actually have `-` therefore I wouldn't find anything.

I could give even more examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not rely on the title part of the url to find the element in the database. Prepend it with some ID and ignore the title. Look at the url of the page you are currently viewing in stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to reverse engineer the *slug* to the actual title in the database to search on. When a user creates a new post, form a slug from the title ("Awesome thread title" -> `awesome-thread-title`), make sure it's unique in the database and *save it in the database*.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you store the "pretty" URL fragment in the database too and use it as a unique index because as you noticed, the "prettifying" is not reversable.